# Which nvidia drivers in additional drivers (please describe drivers)? Please recommend post-install checks

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, xorg

After a lot of work I have got Ubuntu 14.04 (32bit) working on my laptop. I had trouble with the login splash screen freezing, but I resolved it by logging-in in recovery mode and choosing an nvidia rather than Xorg driver. I chose at random and it worked :-) ! (See screen shot).
[image: Additional drivers window]

1. Please can someone explain the different Nvidia drivers to me? Does it matter which I choose (except Xorg which caused the freezing). Have I optimized?
2. Seeing as I had several problems with the install, are there any general checks (not just graphics drivers) that are recommendable to see that all is in order? Superficially everything seems fine. I am, afterall, posting from the said machine now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Best choice would be the binary driver you've selected. Version 331.113 is the most recent version. Tested, I assume, means that it's the most stable version.

The difference between binary and legacy drivers is that legacy drivers provide support for video cards no longer supported by NVIDIA.

Source: [Gladen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/472061/what-is-the-difference-between-an-nvidia-legacy-binary-proprietary-driver-and-a)

The "proprietary" bit following the NVIDIA drivers means that the driver was created by NVIDIA. The "open source" bit following the Nouveau driver means that it was created by the community.

2. You might consider running [System Testing](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/checkbox-qt/) or [Phoronix Test Suite](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/phoronix-test-suite/).

Comment: Thank you. And to clarify what [the link in 1](http://askubuntu.com/questions/472061/what-is-the-difference-between-an-nvidia-legacy-binary-proprietary-driver-and-a) explains: it is best NOT to use legacy if your video card is still supported by Nvidia. And to check whether it is still supported check the _supported products_ tab [here](http://www.nvidia.co.uk/download/driverResults.aspx/75067/en-uk). My video card is **Geforce GT 330M** (see above screenshot), and is listed at the link so is supported.

Comment: I am not sure about 2. as they are badly reviewed. I thought there might just be some standard commands to issue in the terminal rather than software packages. Or a link to post-install tests/drills/important installs.